# Move data from Postgresql to Redis(DB-1)

Tags: postgresql, redis, migration, key, database-migration

I am working on a Spring-MVC application where we are using etherpad as a text editor. Etherpad is saving its contents in DB as simple key,Value pairs. But the performance is too bad for such a simple task and Etherpad doesn't perform any JOIN or other complex operations. For that reason, we decided to migrate to redis. Redis is working, but we have data stuck in postgresql database. How can we move it to Redis 1st database. Here is how the DB looks :

[image]

Redis is working on port 6379 locally.

Comment: You have to migrate it manually. Process the data from Postgres and insert it into Redis

Comment: @TheDude : Ofcourse manually, but how, that's the point.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are stuck on. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TheDude : I am not aware how to enter data into redis without using some wrapper in Java. Other threads which I have found are related to mySQL, that also didn't help. Do you know how I can read from Database and enter it into Redis CLI? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to use a Redis client in Java to connect to Redis and save data. You can find a list of clients here https://redis.io/clients#java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all data in form of `SET` commands and pipe it to `redis-cli` like this:

```
psql -U postgres -W -h localhost store -c "select 'SET \"' || key || '\" \"' || replace(value, '\"', '\\\"') || '\"' from store" -At | redis-cli
```

**Edit**: added escaping of double-quotes with `REPLACE` function

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed, how to select the 1st database in redis to pipe?

Comment: @WeareBorg first database (0) is the default, in case you need to use a different one - you can do so with `-n DBNUM` switch for `redis-cli`

Comment: `redis-cli -n 1`

Comment: Hi. terminal is getting spammed with invalid argument when I run the code. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I am not appending --pipe to redis, but then it complains error writing to server : connection reset by peer.

Comment: It might depend on the actual keys and values you have in your Postgres database - as they might have to be escaped (i.e. double quotes). This works fine for me:

tomasz@MintDev ~ $ echo "SET key1 val1" | redis-cli -n 1
OK
tomasz@MintDev ~ $ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> SELECT 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
1) "key1"
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> get key1
"val1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169942/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-tomasz-poradowski).